# c# Help making values global

Tags: c#, global-variables

so I understand how to make global values and the fact that 1. you shouldn't do it and 2. you cannot use a value that was created in a different "context" however, I'm not sure how to correct this problem in my case. I think it will make sense if you read my code

```
            //read in Load Query TestCSV
        var sourcePath = @"D:\\Load Query test.csv"; //What is the inital CSV
        var delimiter = ",";
        var firstLineContainsHeaders = true; //CSV has headers
        //creates temp file which takes less time than loading into memory
        var tempPath = Path.Combine(@"D:", Path.GetRandomFileName());
        var lineNumber = 0;

        var splitExpression = new Regex(@"(" + delimiter + @")(?=(?:[^""]|""[^""]*"")*$)");

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempPath))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourcePath))
        {
            string line = null;
            string[] headers = null;
            if (firstLineContainsHeaders)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                lineNumber++;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) return; // file is empty;

                headers = splitExpression.Split(line).Where(s => s != delimiter).ToArray();

                writer.WriteLine(line); // write the original header to the temp file.
            }
            var i = 0; //used in 2nd while loop later
            string lines = null;//used in next using statement
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNumber++;

                var columns = splitExpression.Split(line).Where(s => s != delimiter).ToArray();

                //make sure you always have the same number of columns in a line
                if (headers == null) headers = new string[columns.Length];

                if (columns.Length != headers.Length) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Line {0} is missing one or more columns.", lineNumber));
                string badDate = "Date entered incorrectly";                                    //used in next while loop
                // this while loop will read in the user input dateTime and use that to get the column from the PI server.
                //if the date time is entered incorrectly it will tell the user to try to input the datetime again
                while (i==0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter date, ex:16 Jun 8:30 AM 2008, Press enter when done"); //instruct the user in how to enter the date
                    string userInput = Console.ReadLine(); //read in the date the user enters
                    string format = "dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy"; //how the system will read the date entered

                    DateTime dateTime;

                    //if date is entered correctly, parse it, grab the parsed value dateTime and exit loop
                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
                    {                           
                        i = 1; //set the flag to exit while loop
                    }
                    //if input is bad return "Date entered incorrectly and run the loop again
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(badDate);
                        i=0; //set the flag to run the loop again
                    }
                }
                var del = ",";                                                                  //used in next using statement
                var SplitExpression = new Regex(@"(" + del + @")(?=(?:[^""]|""[^""]*"")*$)");   //used in next using statement
                //Use the dateTime from the previous while loop and use it to add each point in "testpts.csv" to "Load Query Test.csv"
                using (StreamReader tags = new StreamReader(@"D:\\testpts.csv"))
                {
                   // string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    string format = "dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
                    lines = tags.ReadLine();
                    var columns1 = SplitExpression.Split(lines).Where(s => s != del).ToArray();
                    var point = PIPoint.FindPIPoint(piServer, lines);
                    var value = point.RecordedValue(dateTime);
                    string returnXml = string.Format(@"<value=""{0}"" />", value);
                    columns[15] = columns[15].Replace("0", returnXml); //column the point should be placed in (in Load Query Test.csv)
                }
                //if statement that will replace any extra 0 testpt values with column 13 values
                if (columns[15].Contains("0"))
                {
                    columns[15] = columns[15].Replace("0", columns[13]);
                }

                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, columns));
            }

        }

        File.Delete(sourcePath); //delete the original csv
        File.Move(tempPath, sourcePath); //replace the old csv with edited one

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm getting the error in the using statement:

```
using (StreamReader tags = new StreamReader(@"D:\\testpts.csv"))
                {
                   // string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    string format = "dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
                    lines = tags.ReadLine();
                    var columns1 = SplitExpression.Split(lines).Where(s => s != del).ToArray();
                    var point = PIPoint.FindPIPoint(piServer, lines);
                    var value = point.RecordedValue(dateTime);
                    string returnXml = string.Format(@"<value=""{0}"" />", value);
                    columns[15] = columns[15].Replace("0", returnXml); //column the point should be placed in (in Load Query Test.csv)
                }
```

In this case the dateTime and userInput values are obviously out of context. I need them created in the previous while loop however because I want the user to be able to enter the correct date only once and ensure that it is entered correctly to make sure the script will actually pull data.

Please let me know if there is another way I can order my code or how I can make userInput and dateTime global. Thank you

Comment: Global variables are not bad to use.

Comment: @deathismyfriend, you are mistaken. They are extremely bad: they make testing extremely difficult; they make tracking down bugs extremely difficult; they make running parts of your code in parallel extremely difficult. All these problems can be significantly reduced by not using global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the "*dateTime*" variable. "*userInput*" is fine, the inner using statement has access to the scope of its outer using statement, because the inner one is part of the outer's scope.

The problem is with "*dateTime*" - the variable is declared inside a while loop, and there is a using block **afterwards** - after the variable is not available anymore, because the scope was disposed - which references a non existent variable.

**Solution**: move the declaration of your dateTime variable out of the while. Say, a line before the while's definition.

Comment: Thank you, this did work for the dateTime variable however, I am still having trouble with the userInput variable. I changed the code to assign it as a string outside the while loop where I had it originally but now I am getting this error in the same using statement that i had before. The error being: "use of unassigned local variable userInput"

Comment: use of unassigned variable is not a scope error (does not mean the variable does not exist in the context you are in.) You fell on another error, which is caused by .NET's CLR requirement of assigning an initial value to any variable you declare and use it throughout your code. Solution: simply change your variable declaration to "string userInput = string.Empty;"

Comment: Does initializing "userInput" now solves the problem? No more errors ?

Comment: Yes I have no errors this way and I feel that is a better solution that making a global property. My only question is totally different now, do you know why my code isn't overwriting my old CSV with the new one I make? 

my Load Query test.csv has 18 columns and 8 rows (not including headers), with the 15th and 16th column being blank. The testpts csv is a single column with 8 rows.

Comment: It's hard to tell without debugging. You should check the definitions of the StreamWriter's constructor you are using. Perhaps it does not overwrite an existing stream. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Without critisizing your code to much ... here an answer. You should be able to walk yourself from here on

Split the declaration of the variable with it's assignment

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

to

```
string userInput;
userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Move the declarations (the first line) outside of the outer Loop.

> Edit: Please, also have a look at [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) (you may call them
>   globals)

Comment: what difference will does this introduce?

Comment: what do I do about the dateTime error? and will the userInput value then carry through to where I read in the testpts csv?

Comment: @Veverke the variable userInput's lifetime gets Extended to the whole outer loop.

Comment: If you meant a change in the variable scope, it's not clear from what you wrote.

Comment: @KarmaEDV You should better explain that the declaration of the variable is outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you, making the userInput a "Property" worked.

Comment: I honestly do not think this is the correct solution :)